# Laplace transform of $y(t)$

Tags: laplace-transform, convolution

Consider two functions g and u over the interval $[0,\infty)$ defined by:
$$
\begin{array}{clll}
g(t)&=e^{-t},\;0\leq t\\[2mm]
u(t)&=\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
1&;&0\leq t\\
0&;&\text{otherwise}\\
\end{array}
\right.
\end{array}
$$

Let $y(t)$ be the function defined by:
$$
y(t)=\int_0^t g(t-\tau )u(\tau) d\tau
$$

(a) Find the Laplace Transform $Y(s)$ for $y(t)$.

(b) Find $y(t)$

---

What I have tried:

(a) $y(t)=\int g(t-\tau) d\tau= \int e^{-(t-\tau)} d\tau = e^{\tau-t}+C$
therefore

$Y(s)=\int e^{-st} e^{\tau-t}d\tau=e^{-t(s+1)+\tau}+C$

Is my starting point correct?

Also, to find complete $y(t)$ do I have to integrate $e^{\tau-t}$ for $0\leq t$ and $t\leq 1$ separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the definition of convolution, $(f*g)(t)=\displaystyle\int_0^t f(\tau)g(t-\tau)d\tau$, then $\mathcal L\{f*g\}=\mathcal L\{f\}\cdot\mathcal L\{g\}$.

Hence we have
\begin{align*}
Y(s)&=\mathcal L\left\{\int_0^t g(t-\tau )u(\tau) d\tau\right\}\\[2mm]
&=\mathcal L\{g(t)\}\cdot \mathcal L\{u(t)\}\\[2mm]
&=\mathcal L\{e^{-t}\}\cdot \mathcal L\{u(t)\}\\[2mm]
&=\dfrac{1}{s+1}\cdot \dfrac{1}{s}\\[2mm]
&=\dfrac{1}{s(s+1)}
\end{align*}
Now using simple fractions we have
\begin{align*}
Y(s)&=\dfrac{1}{s}-\frac{1}{s+1}\\[2mm]
\mathcal L^{-1}\{Y(s)\}&=\mathcal L^{-1}\left\{\dfrac{1}{s}-\frac{1}{s+1}\right\}\\[2mm]
y(t)&=\mathcal L^{-1}\left\{\dfrac{1}{s}\right\}-\mathcal L^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{s+1}\right\}\\[2mm]
y(t)&=u(t)-e^{-t}
\end{align*}